Children's educational show - Canada, french language, teaches biology, UFO
Show specifics:

There's a flying saucer prop, quite large and probably a generic disc shape, with a ladder or ramp for the crew to descend
At least one cast member arrives in this ship, landing on an unknown planet (possibly Earth)
The cast has up to six (but likely fewer) members, who play humans or humanoid aliens. The ship's crew may be costumed in "spaceman"-type metallic garb
The ship's occupants learn about biology (and possibly other subjects), either among themselves or from the planet's native people
The subject matter of the only episode I can recall was "Les Pépins et les Noyaux" - roughly translated, seeds and pits. The cast dissect (and probably eat) various fruits, while explaining the purpose of the seeds, pits, cores, nuts, etc.

Additional info:

Was shown in French Catholic primary schools in the Canadian province of Ontario
There's a high probability the French spoken was of a Parisian-like dialect. This leads me to believe it was filmed in Ontario rather than in Quebec or the maritime - but it could be from France
Distributed on magnetic tape (VHS, possibly Betamax)
Viewed around 1988
Due to the premise, nothing stands out as a hint of when it was made, but it was filmed in color and had quite decent video quality (based on this recollection I would date it late-70's at the earliest)
Probably filmed on an indoor set made to look like the outdoors
May/may not have been a series

